# C# Check if a message contains elements of an array

Tags: c#

i am making a bot to automatically remove spammers from my friendslist.
the links i get as spam is similar to this: Free xx No Deposit to Withdraw!xx:xx/xxxx/xxxSite https://xxxx.xxx
I want to check this message for any word which is from an array which contains various Scam sites. if message contains any of these scam sites, it will run the unfriend function. for some reason it doesnt prase the messages correctly. here is the code what i have so far:

```
if (GlobalConfig.SpamBlackList.Contains(callback.Message) || GlobalConfig.GlobalSpamBlocklist.Contains(callback.Message))
                {
                    SteamFriends.SendChatMessage(callback.Sender, EChatEntryType.ChatMsg, BotConfig.SpamReply); // sends a reply
                    Task.Delay(6000).Wait(); //waits 6 secs
                    SteamFriends.RemoveFriend(callback.Sender); // removes the sender
                 }
```

if i sent a message with just the site link (1 element of the array) it will run and remove the sender. it doesnt work on full messages.
how can i prase each word of the message so that it is more accurate in searching it ?

Comment: `if (GlobalConfig.SpamBlackList.Any(z => callback.Message.Contains(z)) || GlobalConfig.GlobalSpamBlocklist.Any(z => callback.Message.Contains(z)))` might get you started. I'd also suggest adding some kind of weighting against each word (so `Free` might be 50% and `No Deposit` might be 10%) so you can add them up and come up with an overall score.

Comment: As someone who is worked in this space, I can suggest to you that this type of approach is very easy to bypass. Spammers will use, as an example, variant spellings of Paypal to get around it. I'd suggest reading up on Google Safe Browsing. There are also companies that score emails and / or customers based on content and other characteristics. I can't recommend any, but you'll find some with a bit of Googling.

Comment: mjwills, i am working on a steam bot which will remove spammers from my friendslist. i cant base it other than site links because each spam account spam differently. steam usually blocks site links but some are not blocked. if i base it on site links, its easier for me to input site links as i find them into a json file and then process it. 
my problem is was, if i just send the link only, it will remove me, but if i send a full message, it wont. i cant think of a solution here
and yeah, thanks for correction enigmativity

Comment: `i cant base it other than site links because each spam account spam differently` Your problem is not unique. Google around. Trust me, there are companies that do this kind of stuff (I work for an ESP and we use these kinds of services).

Comment: yeah i have been reading that now. i will check it deeper in few hours and update this question if i find an answer to the issue

Comment: i tested if (GlobalConfig.SpamBlackList.Any(z => callback.Message.Contains(z)) || GlobalConfig.GlobalSpamBlocklist.Any(z => callback.Message.Contains(z)))
this with multiple spam messages and it passed all of them. so i guess i need to update the program with this one and then give it a run for few weeks and see if it catchs up every messages.